# How can I get files with dependencies definition?

Tags: dependencies, gradle, dependency-management

How can I get all runtime dependencies that should be copied to `libs` folder with dependencies definition (like module name, artifact id, version)?

Comment: How do you want the dependencies to be organized in the `libs` folder? The artifact ID and version would already be part of the file name usually. What about the group ID?

Comment: Group ID is very important for me. + extracting artifact id from filename is not good. Just flat libs dir with dependencies.

Comment: Sounds like you want to download dependencies to a directory layout similar to how Maven repositories are structured. Do I understand this correctly? I don't think I fully understand your requirements yet as "Just flat libs dir with dependencies." expresses something else.

Comment: By "Just flat libs dir with dependencies." I mean folder similar to `WEB-INF/lib` folder from `.war`

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I misunderstood you but if you want a flat libraries directory this is how you can do it:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into 'libs'
}
```

The group ID would not be part of it of the file name.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But it doesn't solves my problem - still don't have group id + filename is just a convention - I think it may differ from artifactory ID / version

Comment: Would you mind giving us an example on how you would want the copied file names to look like?

Comment: It doesn't matter how they will be copied. I just want to get map: `[fileName: dependencyInfo]` with all resolved compile/runtime dependencies